# Proxy server and other anonymity means

Tags: proxy

I want to use proxy for a little privacy on the Internet. I have read a few information and have several questions. I know a little that there are two methods to attain anonymity in the Internet surfing.

First is to use CGI/proxy script on my own computer or through remote servers such as http://anonymouse.org.

The second one is using proxy servers.

**Questions:**

So the first question is what is the most effective and secure way to implement anonymity on the Internet (what stages of anonymity I can attain by different means)?

How to prevent a probable collection of my information by my Internet provider? I suppose it can collect it through its servers which I use to go out to the Internet.

And the last one is can it be that when a proxy server is used a holder of the server stores and uses my information from requests? How to prevent this? And how to find a reliable and secure proxy servers?

Comment: Not really on-topic here. From the FAQ: Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to ask, but basically your anonymity will still rely on obfuscating the path between your computer and your endpoint.

You sound like you're mixing proxies with anonymity. A proxy can be used to help with anonymity, *if you trust that proxy.* That's how these online anonymizers work. They are proxies because they forward a request for something to the endpoint, then return the result to you. They're "anonymous" because they promise not to hold your connection logs any longer than necessary for the transactions.

But your ISP and anyone between your computer and that proxy will know you connected to that proxy.

You can't entirely anonymize traffic from your computer to the Internet because your provider still knows and can record that traffic from your computer connected to IP blah blah out on the Internet.

If you're looking to anonymize traffic for legitimate purposes, look into Tor, the onion router. It sends your traffic through multiple hosts all over the place to obfuscate your true destination and makes tracing the return path extremely difficult, and you can't control who uses your system as a jump just as they can't control your system using it as a jump point. It's slow, but it anonymizes, and it is used by people all around the world who may get into trouble if organizations/governments know what information they're trafficking.